# Jsp,Servelet URL Difference

Tags: jsp, url, servlets

What's the difference among *Absolute paths* in JSP and *servlets* .
My sample project structure:

```
Dynamic Project name:PathTest
1.html path:PathTest\WebContent\html\1.html
Context root of Project =PathTest
```

I found following things with several tries

1. Inside Test.jsp(under Webcontent):
   link to 1.html ,
   <a href="/PathTest/html/1.html">1.jsp</a><br/>
2. Inside web.xml(under WEB-INF):
   Providing exact aboslute path as I am calling calling Serv servelt from 1.html 
   <url-pattern">/html/Serv.do</url-pattern">
   (/PathTest is not included here)
3. Inside Serv.java:
   Using sendRedirect method to 1.html:
   res.sendRedirect("/PathTest/html/1.html");
4. Inside Serv.java:
   Using getRequestDispatcher method to 1.html:
   RequestDispatcher dispatch=req.getRequestDispatcher("/html/1.html");
   (/PathTest is not included here)

**My question is : Why different Absolute paths required in above case and how container finds resources in such scenarios?**

*I have found a way to avoid such confusion by making context root ='/'
In that way i dont have to include '/PathTest' in any scenarios.**But is it good practice to have context root as '/'?***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/PathTest` is the value of the concept called `context path` in the Servlet/JSP jargon, which is a property of the servlet context.

You are facing two environments: the browser and the Servlet/JSP container.

The browser (ONLY) sees the HTTP protocol, and anything that is transfered over it: HTML, CSS and javascript. When you are generating these content, you need to put `/PathTest` wherever necessary, but that is not all the truth. Now `context path` only makes sense in the Servlet/JSP envrionment. Your browser don't know anything about, it could be dealing with some completely irrelevant technology, even not a JSP container, for all it cares.

In the Servlet/JSP container, you also don't need to specify the value `/PathTest`, and you SHOULDN'T! Use `HttpServletRequest.getContextPath()` to get the actual value if needed.

Now let's look at the cases respectively:

1. In the JSP: `<a href="">...</a>` will output HTML, that is what browsers see, but the content is generated by the JSP container, so you need to put in the *value* of the `context path` so that the link could work correctly.

   <a href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/html/1.html">1.html</a>
2. Inside web.xml, no need to put the `context path`, it's interpreted by the server only, and the server already knows the value of tcontext path already somewhere else.
3. `HttpServletResponse.sendRedirect(String location)` will send a temporary redirect response (HTTP status 3xx) to the browser. Therefore you need to include the context path manually. There are cases when you may want to redirect outside the context path.
4. `HttpServletRequest.getRequestDispatcher(String path)` will only serve as means to forward or include resources *within* the context path.